# Trying to remove tags with Python (BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.example.com/"
result = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
find_by_class = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"class_name"}).find_all('p')
```

I want to print the data without the html tags, but I can't use `get_text()` after the `find_all('p')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a for loop, like so:

```
for i in soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"class_name"}).find_all('p'):
    print(i.get_text())
```

or if you want to save that information, put it into an array:

```
things = []
for i in soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"class_name"}).find_all('p'):
    things.append(i.get_text())
```